# Adding a comma to separate email addresses

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've recently uploaded a clients address list which includes email address.
The email addresses are separated with a comma "," unfortunately when I uploaded the data the comma(s) have been deleted breaking the email functionality.

In the mean time the client has started re-adding the commas, then realizing the enormity of the task, stopped.

Is there a clever SQL query I could write to:

1. Delete any commas added by the client or ignore if already present.
2. Add a comma between all email address.

Appreciate any advice.

Comment: provide data examples of what you have and what you want to look like afterwords

Comment: The SQL way is to store one e-mail adress per row. Comma separated items will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server Manager 17.  example how it looks.  rob@123.co.uk mark@456.co.uk  These need to be separated with either a "," or a ";"

Comment: Found a way to delete the comma, not just need to add back to all.

Comment: This now fixed.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

So I sorted the issue out simply by running this sql script.

`update Customer
set  Email = replace(Email, ' ',';')
WHERE CompanyId = 28;`